# What's the best way to update/insert records into a high-contention InnoDB table in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-deadlocks

I have an InnoDB table in my MariaDB database which gets a lot of writes and also a lot of reads. It's a sort-of "append-only" table like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data              | varchar(225) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_date     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deactivation_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When data is added, it gets INSERTed, of course. When data "changes", I mark the old record as "deactivated" (by setting the field value there) and INSERT the new data.

My code looks something like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id IN (...) FOR UPDATE
foreach row {
   // Do we have a value for this data_id
   if(saves.contains(row.data_id)) {
     // Is it actually NEW?
     if(row.data != saves[row.data_id]) {
       // Disable the record (later)
       disables.add(row.id)
     } else {
       // Preserve the data in the db
       saves.remove(row.data_id);
     }
}
foreach save {
    INSERT...
}
foreach disables {
    UPDATE ... SET deactivation_date=NOW() WHERE id=?
}
```

That pseudocode is awful, but I think you get the point.

In the past, I was first doing an `UPDATE` on everything, then `INSERT`ing whatever was leftover. That got me deadlocks because (I think) the UPDATE was acquiring locks on the table indexes and *then* getting a table-level lock for the `INSERT`. That allowed two separate transactions to hold locks against each other and one would be rolled-back to let the other continue. So I added a simple "try 3 times" logic to my code. :(

I also re-wrote the code to decide what to do, and *then* take action, so I always perform `INSERT`s first, then `UPDATE`s. But I'm still sometimes getting a deadlock. It would be very rare for two simultaneous transactions to overlap in the records they are modifying, so the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` should generally be locking rows which are not currently locked.

What's the best way to perform this `UPDATE`+`INSERT` (or `INSERT`+`UPDATE`) to minimize deadlocks that have to be worked-around (retried) in my own code? Is there a better technique, or should I continue to detect the deadlock and simply retry?

I'm planning to move to Galera Cluster soon where things will get even more complicated and I may have to detect situations where a commit fails because another node in the cluster complains about commit ordering, etc. and I will likely have to implement transaction re-tries, anyway. Does moving to Galera change the answer to the above question at all?

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned that this is, of course, all happening in a transaction with proper rollbacks and all that.

Also, this example table doesn't completely capture the complexity of my use-case where "data_id" is actually ... a lot of things. Not only that, data_id isn't something that can be matched and replaced in its entirety, so `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for two reasons:

1. The PKs are never duplicated
2. The data_id is non-unique for "active" records, so there can be multiple records with the same data_id; the only time the record needs to be disabled is when data coming from the user doesn't exactly match what's in the database (i.e. I'm doing many-to-many differencing to avoid superfluous writes)

Comment: Put the insert/update in a transaction and if either one fails rollback the changes. But this sounds like a case for using the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` syntax for your query. Rolling your own to prevent issues is almost guaranteed to have issues as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Dave. I've updated my question with some further details.

Comment: What is the data source that causes you to have multiple rows to update at the same time? I'm not sure I understand why you have a select for update followed by a foreach against the rows found.

Comment: The SELECT ... FOR UPDATE *is* the loop around the rows found.

Comment: Data is being collected about multiple samples. They can be multi-valued, one row per value. If the data are "updated" (some removals, some adds, some no-changes), then we can't just INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE because there will never be any duplicates, therefore no updates.

Answer (score 0):

In addition what Dave said in the comments:

1. Set your transaction isolation level to READ-COMMITTED. This will prevent adjacent rows from getting locked.
2. Merge the INSERTs into one multi-row INSERT. Note - the entire statement must fit into your `max_allowed_packet` size, so you may need to break it up into a few INSERT statements for large row counts or large payloads.
3. Set your innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 2 if you aren't precious about having gaps in your auto_increment values

Comment: Don't bother with more than 1000 rows in a batch; that is well into the "diminishing returns".